# how do you create a function to load an image per demand

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript to source and load the image:

```
<script>

function heat_map_load() {
    var heat_map="http://example.com/login.png";
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var myImage = new Image();
        $(myImage).load(function () {

            $('#login img').css({ "width": "auto", "height": "auto" });

        }).error(function () {
            $('#login').hide();
        }).attr('src', heat_map)
    });
}
</script>
```

html:

```
<a class="profile" style="width: 100px;" id="web_login_p" href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="1m">heat map</a>


<div class="main" id="login" style="width:700px; height:300px;"></div>
```

JavaScript to load the image per click:

```
$("#web_login_p").click(function() {
    heat_map_load();
});
```

when I click the web_login_p, I get heat_map_load not defined error. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: You should define `heat_map_load` method outside document-ready handler

Comment: Move the heat_map_load function outside of the `$(document).ready`

Comment: Don't move it outside the `.ready` - move the click handler in. Also, use consistent naming scheme (so heatMapLoaded in this case). or better - don't have a .ready in the first place and put the code at the end of the body.

Comment: not defined means javascript not getting the function when called. This can happen when the function definition is not before the call. Check the function script is loaded before the later javascript.

Comment: @Satpal I've made your recommendation, no difference. I cannot load the image per click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heat_map_load` is not defined because it is visible only in local scope, which is `document.ready` handler.
Benjamin is right, you should move the click handler in `.ready`. Here is working example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var heat_map = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
    function heat_map_load() {

        var myImage = new Image();
        $('#login').append($(myImage));
        $(myImage).load(function () {

            $('#login img').css({ "width": "auto", "height": "auto" });


        }).error(function () {
            $('#login').hide();
        }).attr('src', heat_map);

    }
    $("#web_login_p").click(function() {
        heat_map_load();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mnTyG/

Comment: I do have an append in there. If something already exists in the login div, it appends to it. I need to replace whatever in login div with the image. what can I use instead of append?

Comment: For example, `$('#login').html($(myImage));`